# Openresty : getting issue with ngx.re.gsub to handle magic characters of lua

Tags: lua, openresty

I want to replace a word into my body content from other string .
To implement this i am using **ngx.re.sgub**  but i am getting a weird issue. **ngx.re.gsub** is not handling magic characters.

- Example :

  ```
  content1 = "HiTestHello Test how are you Testall "
  _ssi = "Test"
  body = "$100.00"
  content2 = ngx.re.gsub(content1, _ssi, body)
  ngx.print(content2)
  ```

output is

```
Hi.00lHelo .00 how are you .00all he.00llo .00 how are you .00all
```

while output should like :

```
Hi$100.00Hello .00 how are you .00all.
```

Please let me know how can i achieve this .

Answer (score 1):

In ngx regex, `$1`, `$2`, etc. are variable to be captured. Try escape the `$` character:

```
body = "$$100.00"
```

Comment: value of body is dynamic which is coming from my cms and i can not make changes there .
Please help me to find out other way to fix this .

Comment: @PrashantGaur At least try to see if it's this issue because I don't have an environment to test.

Comment: As per your suggestion if i am putting body = $$100.00 it is working fine . i think i can parse body data and look if any $ or other character exists then i will convert $ into $$ .

Comment: You can wait to see if others can provide a native solution to that, but your method sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `body` with a function also avoids it:

```
content1 = "HiTestHello Test how are you Testall "
_ssi = "Test"
body = "$100.00"
content2 = ngx.re.gsub(content1, _ssi, function()
    return body
end, "o")
ngx.print(content2)
```